# Swift List of Protocols and Generic Methods

Tags: swift

I have a structure describing a list of views

```
struct A<T: View> {
   let view: T.Type
}

struct B<???> {
    let items: [A<???>]
}
```

And would like to describe the app the following way

```
let content = [
    B(items: [
         A(view: View1.self),
         A(view: View2.self)
    ])
]
```

What's the generic type of `B`? Can I somehow get it to work? The same was as just declaring `view` as `View` in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're not looking to just use metatypes. If you are, the metatype is built into the type. You don't need to store it:

```swift
struct A<View: SwiftUI.View> { }

struct B<View: SwiftUI.View> {
  let items: [A<View>]
}

struct View: SwiftUI.View {
  var body: some SwiftUI.View {
    Text("⚔️")
  }
}

let content = [
  B<View>(items: [A(), A()])
]
```

Otherwise, use Frankenstein's answer. ⚡️

Comment: Why have you used SwiftUI? It is not mentioned in the question anywhere.

Comment: It's possible you're right, but I doubt you're right. Let's hear from vasily!

Answer (score 1):

You just need this:

```
struct A<T: View> {
   let view: T
}

struct B<T: View> {
    let items: [A<T>]
}
let content = [
    B(items: [
         A(view: View1),
         A(view: View2)
    ])
]
```

Comment: The `View1` and `View2` are confusing here because they're neither instances nor metatypes.

Comment: @Jessy that's true from an ios perspective.